# Question, How do I query a database to browse albums by genre id?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Doing a assignment where I need to browse albums by genre Id.  I have three views:

"Browse" which is displaying genres (I got it done)

"Index" which displays albums by a genre(which is where I am stuck at)

"Details" (which displays details about an album)

I am told to query the data base with parameters of int id, but I am confused on how to do this as in my book, it does it with strings only.

So far I can only get it to display all albums when I click on any genre.

Here is my **controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MVCMusicStoreApplication.Models;

namespace MVCMusicStoreApplication.Controllers
{
    public class StoreController : Controller
    {
        private MVCMusicStoreApplicationDB db = new MVCMusicStoreApplicationDB();
        // GET: Store
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Browse()
        {
            return View(db.Genres.ToList());
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index(int id)
        {

            //var album = db.Albums.Find(id);
            return View(db.Albums.ToList());
        }

        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var album = db.Albums.Find(id);
            return View(album);

        }


    }
}
```

**My Index View**

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCMusicStoreApplication.Models.Album>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    <ul>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "Details", new { id = item.AlbumId }) </li>
    </ul>
```

**Browse view**

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCMusicStoreApplication.Models.Genre>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Browse";
}

<h2>Browse</h2>


@foreach(var item in Model)
{

<ul>
<li>@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Index", new { id = item.GenreId }) </li>
</ul>


}
```

Comment: So you want to click on a Genre (in the Browse view) and display all albums for that genre? Where is the code for your Browse view? You need to post the genre ID to an action that filters your albums with that genre id

Comment: Correct.  I added my browse view code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to filter the result from your db query

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {

        //var album = db.Albums.Find(id);
        return View(db.Albums.Where(x => x.IDGenre == id).ToList());
    }
```

I assume that you have a IDGenre in the Album model, (change this name to the correct field name) and thus you can apply a simple linq condition to the Albums sequence.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

I feel stupid that it was that simple but the book  didn't explain the int version.

I appreciate it :)